# Lightning event createRecord without Popup?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-experience

i am using following code snippet for createRecord. Question is it works great but as Popup div-layer modal window and I **do not** want to have Popup window.

*Question* Is it possible to override navigation behavior not to use popup but navigate to and open page similar to event 'e.force:navigateToRelatedList'

```
createRecord : function (component) {
    var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Event__c"
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire();
}
```

Comment: One way to handle this scenario is to adding a ui:spinner to your ui component and display message like "in process".

Comment: question is about not displaying as popup window. I need to display it as Page.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Did you figure this out?

Comment: It looks like it cannot be done. Since listviews are predefined queries, there is no way to add filter. Let me know if you have more info.

Comment: I thought you created a component and implementing force:lightningQuickAction or force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader interface. and i was going to say to remove these and it should work fine. If that was a wrong assumption then it is fine.